# Is there an elegant way to re write my angular code?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi Currently i have an angular 5 project . i have a method named createForm. it will basically create just a form. however the form created changes depends on the flight inventory code . if flight inventory code id TAG_ON i will create a form omitting messagePrefixSMSValidator   and also form control named message to empty. so following is my code.

```
 createForm() {

    this.formGroup = this.fb.group(
      {
        defaultTemplate: [this.defaultInitialValue],
        language: [null, Validators.required],
        message: [ this.messagePrefix ? this.messagePrefix:'', [Validators.required]],
        longUrl: ['']
      },
      {
        validator: [
                    hasUrlTagValidator(TemplatesService.urlTag), 
                    messagePrefixSMSValidator(this.messagePrefix? this.messagePrefix: null, 'message')
                  ]
      }
    );

   if(this.flight.inventory.code === FlightInventoryCode.TAG_ON) {

    this.formGroup =  this.fb.group(
      {
        defaultTemplate: [this.defaultInitialValue],
        language: [null, Validators.required],
        message: [ '', [Validators.required]],
        longUrl: ['']
      },
      {
        validator: [
                    hasUrlTagValidator(TemplatesService.urlTag), 
                  ]
      }
    );
   }

  }
```

so is there a way to rewrite my code so that it looks simple.

really appreciate any help
thanks

Comment: This seems to belong to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if there is no problem in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function createForm() {
  const isTagOn = this.flight.inventory.code === FlightInventoryCode.TAG_ON;
  const message = [
    isTagOn ? "" : this.messagePrefix || "",
    [Validators.required]
  ];
  const validator = [hasUrlTagValidator(TemplatesService.urlTag)];
  if (!isTagOn) {
    validator.push(
      messagePrefixSMSValidator(this.messagePrefix || null, "message")
    );
  }

  this.formGroup = this.fb.group(
    {
      defaultTemplate: [this.defaultInitialValue],
      language: [null, Validators.required],
      message,
      longUrl: [""]
    },
    {
      validator
    }
  );
}
```